# Localhost redirected you too many times in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller: this page this 3 methods and 1 view, it's basically a career apply page where you give your details and get an email and mobile otp validation. I have one view, using viewbag I'm taking the data from the user and if there is already data in the form it will go to else condition but when I submit the otp which I received will throw this error.

```
public ActionResult RequestForJob( string JobTitle = "")
{ 
    FillViewBagData("RequestForJob");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobTitle))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    ViewBag.JobTitle = JobTitle;
    ViewBag.msg = "";
    ViewBag.IsFirstTimeLoad = true;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestForJob(string JobTitle, string Name, string Mobile, string Email, string Message, HttpPostedFileBase Resume)
{
    FillViewBagData("RequestForJob");
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    ViewBag.JobTitle = JobTitle;
    ViewBag.Name = Name;
    ViewBag.Mobile = Mobile;
    ViewBag.Email = Email;
    ViewBag.Message = Message;

    try
    {
        if (Resume != null)
        {
            fileName = new ImageService().UploadImageAsync(Resume, AzureFileUploaderPath.files).Result;
            ViewBag.msg = new WebsiteHelper().SendOtp(Mobile, Email);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new HelperFactory().LogtoSQL2(ex, "Website");
        ViewBag.msg = ex.Message;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.msg))
    {
        ViewBag.IsFirstTimeLoad = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.IsFirstTimeLoad = false;
    }

    ViewBag.ResumeFile = fileName;
    ViewBag.JobTitle = JobTitle;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestForJobVerify(string JobTitle, string Name, string Mobile, string Email, string Message, string EmailOtp, string MobileOtp, string ResumeFile)
{
    FillViewBagData("RequestForJob");
    ViewBag.JobTitle = JobTitle;
    ViewBag.Name = Name;
    ViewBag.Mobile = Mobile;
    ViewBag.Email = Email;
    ViewBag.Message = Message;
    ViewBag.ResumeFile = ResumeFile;
               
    try
    {
        ViewBag.OtpMsg = new WebsiteHelper().VerifyOtp(Mobile, Email, EmailOtp, MobileOtp);

        if (ViewBag.OtpMsg == "Success")
        {
            new WebsiteHelper().SendJobEmail(JobTitle, Name, Mobile, Email, Message, ResumeFile);
            return View("ThankYou");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new HelperFactory().LogtoSQL2(ex, "Website");
        ViewBag.OtpMsg = ex.Message;
    }

    ViewBag.IsFirstTimeLoad = false;

    return View("RequestForJob");
}
```

And my view looks like this: please tell me why is it showing me the error redirected so many times

```
   <!-- contact form section - start
    -->
    <div class="contact-form-section">
        <div class="contact-form-section-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-0 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-10 offset-1">
                        <!--
                        contact form - start
                        -->
                        <div class="contact-form drop-shadow-2">
                            <div class="contact-form-wrapper">
                                <div class="section-heading section-heading-2 center">
                                    <div class="sub-heading c-purple upper ls-1">
                                        <i class="las la-envelope"></i>
                                        <h5>You're Raising Enquiry for</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="main-heading c-dark">
                                        <h4>@ViewBag.JobTitle</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="JobTitle" value="@ViewBag.JobTitle" />
                                    @if (ViewBag.IsFirstTimeLoad)
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="Name" id="name-field" type="text" placeholder="Full name" required value="@ViewBag.Name">
                                            <label for="name-field">Full name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="Mobile" id="m-field" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" maxlength="10" min="10" required value="@ViewBag.Mobile">
                                            <label for="email-field">Mobile Number</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="Email" id="email-field" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@Html.Raw("@[a-z0-9.-]")+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" value="@ViewBag.Email">
                                            <label for="email-field">Email address</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="Message" id="message-field" type="text" placeholder=" Your Message" required value="@ViewBag.Message">
                                            <label for="message-field">Message</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="Resume" id="message-field" type="file" placeholder=" Your Message" required>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="form-floating" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
                                            <label style="color:red;">@ViewBag.msg</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button button-2" formmethod="post">
                                            <span class="button-inner">
                                                <span class="button-content">
                                                    <span class="text">Submit Resume</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input name="Name" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Name">
                                        <input name="Mobile" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Mobile">
                                        <input name="Email" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Email">
                                        <input name="Message" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Message">
                                        <input name="ResumeFile" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.ResumeFile">
    
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="MobileOtp" id="textInput-field" type="password" placeholder="Mobile Number OTP">
                                            <label for="Mobileotp-field">Enter Mobile OTP</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="input form-control" name="EmailOtp" id="emailotp-field" type="password" placeholder="Email OTP">
                                            <label for="Emailotp-field">Enter Email OTP</label>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="form-floating" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
                                            <label style="color:red;">@ViewBag.OtpMsg</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button button-2" formaction="/Home/RequestForJob" formmethod="post">
                                            <span class="button-inner">
                                                <span class="button-content">
                                                    <span class="text">Resend OTP</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button button-2" formaction="/Home/RequestForJobVerify" formmethod="post">
                                            <span class="button-inner">
                                                <span class="button-content">
                                                    <span class="text">Submit</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    }
    
                                    <div class="form-floating">
                                        <label for="message-field">You can also reach us on <a href="mailto:hr@xpay.life">hr@xpay.life</a> </label>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--
                        contact form - end
                        -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your code, there is only one place where redirection happens. `return RedirectToAction("index");` Did you debug you code and see from where the redirection is happening? `it will go to else condition` can you point to the `else` part in the code above?

Comment: hello chethan , thank you for responding.Well the problem is in 3rd method i.e RequestForJobVerify once i hit submit otp it won't hit that method.